# Renaming multiple files in a nested structure

Tags: bash, rename, file-rename

I have a directory with this structure:

```
root
|-dir1
| |-pred_20181231.csv
|
|-dir2
| |-pred_20181234.csv
...
|-dir84
  |-pred_2018123256.csv
```

I want to run a command that will rename all the `pred_XXX.csv` files to `pred.csv`.

How can I easily achieve that?

I have looked into the [rename facility](https://www.tecmint.com/rename-multiple-files-in-linux/) but I do not understand the perl expression syntax.

EDIT: I tried with this code: `rename -n 's/\training_*.csv$/\training_history.csv/' *.csv` but it did not work

Comment: Check out this FAQ: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/030

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use some shell looping:

```
for file in **/*.csv
do
    echo mv "$(dirname "$file")/$(basename "$file")" "$(dirname "$file")/pred.csv"
done
```

On modern shells `**` is a wildcard that matches multiple directories in a hierarchy, an alternative to `find`, which is a fine solution too.  I'm not sure if this should instead be `/**/*.csv` or `/root/**/*.csv` based on tree you provided, so I've put `echo` before the 'mv' to see what it's about to do.  After making sure this is going to do what you expect it to do, remove the `echo`.

Answer (score 4):

Try with this command:

```
find root -type f -name "*.csv" -exec perl-rename 's/_\d+(\.csv)/$1/g' '{}' \;
```

**Options used**:

- `-type f` to specify file or directory.
- `-name "*.csv"` to only match files with extension `csv`
- `-exec\-execdir` to execute a command, in this case, `perl-rename`
- `'s/_\d+(\.csv)/$1/g'` search a string like `_20181234.csv` and replace it with `.csv`, `$1` means first group found.

**NOTE**

Depending in your S.O. you could use just `rename` instead of `perl-rename`.